# How to properly organize a module for node.js

Tags: node.js, module, packaging

I'm currently learning **node.js**.

I'd like to create a module named **'bio'** that would contain some native C++ extensions and some javascript code.

I've generated a simple "package.json" file with **npm init** in the root directory and my c++ sources in the **src/** folder. The C++ file is compiled to  /build/extension.node .

```
/package.json
/build/extension.node
/src/extension.cpp
```

- Where should I put the javascript files ?
- how should I tell `node` that my javascript files are part of the 'bio' package ?
- how should I set the `$NODE_PATH` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The javascript files are commonly put to `./lib/`. Check small NPM packages such as `dirty` or `request` for examples.

To tell node the package name put `package.json` and other files to a `bio` folder.

You should not set `NODE_PATH`. You should rely on `node_modules` convention instead.

Read http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_folders_as_modules and related documentation.